# Discussion of a new tag for physical positioning issues aside from fingering

Tags: discussion, tags

For the piano, and perhaps other instruments, we get a fair number of questions about hand/arm/wrist positions and motions for efficiently executing passages, producing good tone, and other issues related to "fingering", but often separate from it.

Right now we don't have an obvious tag for such issues, though in a broad sense they could fit with [fingering](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingering). However, these questions would seem to deserve their own tag because

1. They are a sufficiently unique and common category of issue, and
2. Tags like [fingering](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingering) or [physiology](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physiology) don't obviously apply.

My feeling is we should have such a tag, but I don't immediately have a term that would apply across instruments. Maybe [physical-positioning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-positioning)? There is a largely unused [ergonomics](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics) tag that would seemingly fit, but again, not an immediately obvious term (though increased use for this purpose might promote its further use).

**Thoughts on whether a tag would be helpful and what that tag should be?**

---

**UPDATE:** A closer read of the [physiology](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physiology) and [ergonomics](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics) tag wikis indicates they are intended for this purpose. My current take is that these are the tags to use and, since they are non-obvious, will require experienced users to appropriately tag questions that miss them.

Answer (score 8):

I agree - looking at both [ergonomics](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics) and [physical-positioning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-positioning), I think they are synonyms. I'd suggest making [ergonomics](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics) the primary, with [physical-positioning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-positioning) being a synonym, and then updating the description

Comment: To follow through on your suggestion, I would create the physical-positioning tag, get a score of 5 with it, and then propose the synonym. Is there a more efficient way? Can mods or higher rep users create/propose synonyms directly?

Comment: yup - mods can do it, and we do a lot of that in the early stages of a site. Now this site is mature we try wait until there is a number of folks in support. I like it, but let's see if any of our other folks pitch in

Comment: In piano terminology the most common and down to earth terminology for explaining efficient hand motion in passagework is "hand-wrist alignment". That has to do with physical positioning, but it's more specific, since physical positioning is also about posture in general. "Physical alignment" come to mind but again I prefer "hand-wrist-alignment" which covers all kind of issues with facility in playing an instrument.

Comment: It appears that the "physiology" tag is already intended for this purpose.